# How to change background color of a comment inserted in MS Word document?

Tags: vba, ms-word, comments

When I enter a comment in a document by clicking `Review -> Comments -> New Comment` in MS Word 2010, word allows me to enter a comment. However, I am not able to change the background color of the comment box.

Is there a way by which background color of the comment box can be changed in MS Word?

I am asking this because, I am writing a VBA code to read all the comments inserted in a document. I also want to get information about the background color of the comment box. So, if it can be done using tools provided in the ribbon, it can be done through VBA as well. With this notion in mind, I am asking this.

Comment: Looks like it's `Comment.Scope.Font.Fill.BackColor.RGB`... can't confirm because I lack Word 2010 on this computer.

Comment: @DanielCook: Could you achieve the desired behaviour on whatever version of MS Word you have?

Comment: No, and I was wrong about the Scope. To reach the text of the Comment you need to just get the Range of the comment, but that doesn't seem to matter. As Ahmad pointed out in his answer the Comment's color seems to be defined by the author. You can determine or even change the author of a comment by referencing `Commnet.Author`, which may get you what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Ahmad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13319608/1316573) indicated, you can change the color of a comment by having the comment have a different author.

You can access all of the comments via ActiveDocument.Comments.

Something like the following:

```
dim c as Comment
For each c in ActiveDocument.Comments
    'Give each comment a unique author.
    c.Author = "Author" & c.Index
next
```

Would change the author of every comment, and each comment would have a different color.

That being said, you should be able to read all comments and figure out if the colors are the same by tracking the author of the comment. However, there does not appear to be any practical way to update the color of the comment via code or even know the actual comment color.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that in Word, comments background color can't be decided by you, but they can be changed randomly (at least to me) by changing the username of the current user.

For example, I originally had all my comments in pink boxes. Until I executed this

```
Application.UserName = "Ahmad MUTAWA"
```

After that, each comment I added is in a violet box. I did another change,

```
Application.UserName = "Ahmad"
```

and yet my new comments were added into a another shade of pink. Look at the attached screenshot. These comments appear in three different colors, but they all were added by me under different usernames.
[image: Comments Color]

So what you can do is look for comments written by different `Reviewer`s since each reveiwer is essentially a username.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ahmad for the answer. Accepting other answer as it has a code snippet and if anyone sees this post, they would appreciate the same.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Review-> Track Changes` Option and it will give you (the author) a chance to change the color of your comments so you can change it to a different color than red and blue